# How to use Google Cross-Client Identity on Android to authenticate Web API 2 under same project?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, katana

I have been researching Authentication & Authorization using ASP.NET Web API 2 for about 2-3 weeks & after lot of researching & reading I am able to agree upon the basic architecture for my project.

My project currently consists:

1. ASP.NET Web API 2 backend (OWIN/Katana)
2. Android App

I am referring [Cross-client Identity](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth) to generate **access_token** & **refresh_token** *for* the **Web API 2** project; where access_token is generated on Android App for the Web API using [GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil)

The access token (bearer) doesn't work on Web API and is remarkably shorter in length as compared to the one generated at the Web API side using OWIN Middleware.

I think I am accurately following all the steps correctly, unless I am doing something fundamentally wrong.